# encoding utf-8 python from file UTF-8 to other file

Tags: python

I have two files in UTF-8, I need merge this files with a Python script, for each line in f1 (read by readlines() method), I do a writeline(l) in f2, but I need that f2 be UTF-8 file, How I can dou?

Thanks

Comment: If you write utf-8 bytes that you read from another file to a new file, it's a utf-8 file. (Although how you opened the file in the first place and what version of Python you're using are probably relevant.)

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: f=open("f1.sql", "r")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open method from the codecs module (instead of `open(file,'w')`):

```
import codecs

fileNames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

with codecs.open('file3.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as outfile:
    for fname in fileNames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
line.encode('utf-8')
```

in case it's not already encoded with utf-8. It should be though, when both files are initially utf-8. 
You can also open the file in python with a given encoding:

```
file = open("C:\test.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
```